# Windows Socket Programming - Error Code 0

Tags: c++, c, windows

Im trying to create a program using Windows sockets and i am getting an error code 0 when trying to create the socket

```
int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
}

csocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 

if(csocket != INVALID_SOCKET){
    wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

The part that is failing is creating the socket and the output i am getting is "socket function failed with error: 0.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` condition is wrong and the socket descriptor is actually being created as it does not equal `INVALID_SOCKET`.

Change to:

```
if (csocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
    wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
}
```

Comment: wait never mind i had the check wrong. Thank you, that fixed it.